# dynamically wrap and unwrap elements: not working

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to present a series of images in a particular way by controlling them with a parent div wrapper in varying sized groups.

I need to be able to wrap these images in parent classes only if a browser is at and/or beyond 960px, else don't wrap them. But I need to be able to dynamically remove or add these classes if a user manually resizes their browser.

At the moment this is kind-of working, until I resize my browser. If a wrapper class has been removed it won't be re-added when the browser is at or beyond 960px.

```
      // look for items to be wrapped
      var elems = $(".instagram-post");

      // control the parent wrappers start positions
      var sizes = [1,2,3,2];

      // Add or removes wrapper class depending on screen width.
        function screenClass() {
            if($(window).innerWidth() >= 960) {
                for (var row = 0; row < sizes.length; row++) {
                    var wrapper = $("<div>").addClass("wrap_row_" + (row+1));
                    $(elems.splice(0, sizes[row])).wrapAll(wrapper);
                }
            } else {
                    $(".instagram-post").unwrap(".wrap_row_1");
                }
            }

        // Fire.
        screenClass();

        // And recheck when window gets resized.
        $(window).bind('resize',function(){
            screenClass();
        });
```

Comment: `.bind()` is deprecated since WW2. Use `.on()` instead. Also, `$(window).on('resize',function(){
            screenClass();
        });` does the same as  `$(window).on('resize',screenClass);`.

Comment: "WW2" means _as of jQuery 3.0_.

Comment: It seems all you are trying to do is styling-related. Why don't you use CSS for this?